# How to check if a list of intervals (Joda-Time) fully covers a month in Java

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library in Java to keep track a list of time [intervals](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_interval.html). I want to check if a list of [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) objects fully covers every minute of a month. There's about 30 intervals of varying length from a few hours to a few days.

I thought a cheap way to do this is to sort the list of intervals by start time, then successively check if there is a break between the intervals within the range of the month. If yes, then the month is not fully covered.

I'm stuck on the first part, sorting the list. I planned to use [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).sort(), but it needs the elements to implement the comparable interface. However, after looking through the source, Joda-Time's Interval class doesn't seem to have one I can override, and I can't extend it to write my own compareTo method.

Other than writing my own sorting method, anyone know an easier way to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next method

```java
static boolean covers(Interval month, List<Interval> intervals)
{
  //assumes intervals are sorted already on start times
  final MutableInterval monthInterval = new MutableInterval(month);
  start: for (final Interval interval : intervals)
  {
     if (interval.getStartMillis() <= monthInterval.getStartMillis()
        && interval.getEndMillis() > monthInterval.getStartMillis())
     {
        if (interval.getEndMillis() > monthInterval.getEndMillis())
        {
           return true;
        }
        monthInterval.setStartMillis(interval.getEndMillis());
        // continue start;  // loop continues regardless
     } else {
           if (interval.overlaps(month)) return false;
     }
  }
  return monthInterval.getStartMillis()== monthInterval.getEndMillis();
}
```

**Example**

```
   static final List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
   static
   {
      intervals.add(new Interval(new DateTime(1990, 05, 15, 00, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(1990, 05, 18, 00, 00, 00, 00)));
      intervals.add(new Interval(new DateTime(1990, 04, 28, 00, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(1990, 05, 18, 00, 00, 00, 00)));
      intervals.add(new Interval(new DateTime(1990, 05, 17, 00, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(1990, 05, 21, 00, 00, 00, 00)));
      intervals.add(new Interval(new DateTime(1990, 05, 21, 00, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(1990, 05, 29, 00, 00, 00, 00)));
      intervals.add(new Interval(new DateTime(1990, 05, 22, 00, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(1990, 05, 25, 00, 00, 00, 00)));
      intervals.add(new Interval(new DateTime(1990, 05, 27, 00, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(1990, 06, 02, 00, 00, 00, 00)));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      final DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(1990, 05, 01, 00, 00);
      final Interval monthInterval = new Interval(startOfMonth, startOfMonth.plusMonths(1));

      covers(monthInterval, intervals);
   }

   static boolean covers(Interval month, List<Interval> intervals)
   {
      final MutableInterval monthInterval = new MutableInterval(month);
      start: for (final Interval interval : intervals)
      {
         if (interval.getStartMillis() <= monthInterval.getStartMillis()
            && interval.getEndMillis() > monthInterval.getStartMillis())
         {
            if (interval.getEndMillis() > monthInterval.getStartMillis())
            {
               return true;
            }
            monthInterval.setStartMillis(interval.getEndMillis());
            continue start;
         }
      }
      return monthInterval.getStartMillis()== monthInterval.getEndMillis();
   }
```

Comment: AS you have single loop you do not need that flag for continue.

Comment: I made this solution work after initially sorting the intervals using Katja's recommendation. Otherwise, this alg can't tell where the gaps are. Then return false on failure of the first if statement because it would indicate a gap between the previous and the current intervals. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Collections#sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort the time intervals and use [`Interval#gap`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#gap%28org.joda.time.ReadableInterval%29) to check for gaps. The following code returns true if the interval between start and end is fully covered by the timeIntervals:

```
public static boolean isCovered(List<Interval> timeIntervals, DateTime start, DateTime end) {
    if (timeIntervals.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }

    // create sorted set from original List to get
    // sorted intervals without double entries
    Set<Interval> intervalSet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<Interval>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Interval o1, Interval o2) {
            return o1.getStart().compareTo(o2.getStart());
        }
    });
    intervalSet.addAll(timeIntervals);

    List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<>(intervalSet);

    // remove intervals completely contained in others
    List<Interval> removedIntervals = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (intervals.size()-1); i++) {
        for (int j = (i+1); j < intervals.size(); j++) {
            if (intervals.get(i).contains(intervals.get(j))) {
                if (!removedIntervals.contains(intervals.get(j))) {
                    removedIntervals.add(intervals.get(j));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    intervals.removeAll(removedIntervals);

    if (intervals.get(0).getStart().isAfter(start) ||
            intervals.get(intervals.size() - 1).getEnd().isBefore(end)) {
        return false;
    }

    // check for gaps
    for (int i = 0; i < (intervals.size() - 1); i++) {
    Interval gap = intervals.get(i).gap(intervals.get(i+1));
        if (gap != null && new Interval(start, end).overlaps(gap)) {
            // gap detected between interval i and interval (i+1)
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: One more issue http://www.writeurl.com/text/nrjd4lcaq755cuuy18qv/vrvmq98otd592waszkxp

Comment: I cann't draw this in comment)

Comment: @Ilya Ok, can you put it in words? If there is an error, I'd like to know so I can correct it ;)

Comment: Intervals: **1)** 3 - 10, **2)** 4 - 5, **3)** 6-11. 2 and 3 have a gap, so this will return `false`

Comment: @Ilya You are right, thanks for pointing that out. I'll fix it.